# Interesting javascript code in configuration options in MathJax

Tags: javascript, configuration, mathjax

As far as I know the javascript code can be "defined" as file

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
```

or as inline code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
....
// some more code
....
</script>
```

So, how this is done ? Nevertheless this is javascript code !?!

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="MathJax.js">
   MathJax.Hub.Config({
      extensions: ["tex2jax.js", "mml2jax.js"],
      jax: ["input/Tex", "input/MathML", "output/HTML-CSS"]
   });
</script>
```

[Video](http://www.mathjax.org/resources/articles-and-presentations/integrating-mathjax/) configuring MathJax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Found out from looking at MathJax demos with Chrome's developer tools)

It's programmatically creating new `<script>` tags and places them inside the `<head>` tag, rather like http://requirejs.org/ or http://headjs.com/ does.

Something along the lines of

```
var scr = document.createElement('script');
scr.setAttribute('src', 'path/to/script.js');
headDOMnode.appendChild(src); // 'path/to/script.js' starts to load..
```

happens when `MathJax.Hub.Config()` executes.

**Edit:** head.js and require.js does it with rather a lot more bells and whistles, of course.

Answer (score 1):

This is just some invalid markup. Excerpt from specs follows (note the usage of *must* rather than *should*):

> If the src attribute is not set, user
>   agents must interpret the contents of
>   the element as the script. If the src
>   has a URI value, user agents must
>   ignore the element's contents and
>   retrieve the script via the URI.

Comment: @Bakudan "may be"? Are you sure you've read the specs? *Standard* behaviour stated in quote above. If you don't believe the specification, i guess i cannot help you further.